How to get Steam Wishlist info of another user?
As of November 2024, Steam has deprecated the old way of using
https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/profiles/${steamID}/wishlistdata/
https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/id/${steamID}/wishlistdata

Now it redirect to the main page.
Is there any different method to get wishlist data for user? Anything that doesn't involve headless browser for scraping?

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0001.29 . If it's in the API, you can get it. Web scraping is probably against Steam's terms of service (you should check) and/or they probably have defence mechanisms which could get your client code's IP banned, etc. It's not a great idea.

P.S. If you do want to try scraping, it looks like a wishlist can currently be found at https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/${steamID}/wishlist/ - easily to spot that by simply looking at the link to the wishlist from your own account in the browser and seeing what URL it points to. Note that this then does a (temporary, 302) redirect to https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/profiles/${steamID}/ so you need to follow that. Did you actually investigate this at all? It's only a few moments' work to look at it using your browser's developer tools

P.S. Just a terminology note: Steam has deprecated...no, they've removed it, since it no longer works. "deprecation", in the software world anyway, is when you announce that you plan to remove something in the future, so that people have time to adapt their code or integrations. When you deprecate something you don't actually remove it immediately, that removal only happens some time later. I mention this because using correct terminology when you describe a situation is important, so that everyone understands the exact situation, and there's no scope for confusion/contradiction/ambiguity

P.P.S. Note that wishlists are not public, so unless you have done something you're not telling us about here, it's unclear how you expect to scrape the wishlist for another user (or why you want to!).

@ADyson The former method was used internally by Steam, so they deprecate it for their own use, it was more like a backdoor than an actual API. As for the method of scrapping it from the page you suggested, it only loads certain amount of content on the first load, and I couldn't figure out how the lazy load mechanic there works to mimic it with fetch calls.

For scraping modern pages, especially ones with lots of fetch calls or dynamically generated content, you're usually far better with a headless browser tool than traditional scraping with a basic HTTP client. I know you said you didn't want to use one (although you gave no reason for this restriction), but that's the reality. It may be possible to imitate the behaviour of the fetch requests if you analyse them really carefully but if there are a lot of them, or they don't fire off the same way every time, then it may be a very tedious and long-winded process to get it right.
